# ibm http server internal server error

Tags: load-balancing, websphere-7, websphere-portal, internal-server-error, ibmhttpserver

I'm using 2 Websphere Portal nodes with IBM Http Server as a load balancing proxy. When performing a complex operation (complex database query) using a proxy, I'm getting Internal Server Error after 120 seconds. When I log in directly to Websphere node whithout a proxy, the error doesn't occur.
I was browsing httpd.conf file but found only Timeout property set to 3000 seconds.
Does anyone know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `plugin-cfg.xml` file you need to modify `ServerIOTimeout` in the Server element like:

```
<Server Name="server1" ServerIOTimeout=300>
```

You can find location of the plugin-cfg.xml file at the end of your `httpd.conf` file.

This property defines how long plugin will wait (in seconds) for the response from server before marking it down. So you need to set it to the longest transaction you expect. 
  If you set negative value (-300), server will be marked down (unavailable), if timeout is reached.

See details here [plugin-cfg.xml definition](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rwsv_plugincfg.html?lang=en)